# How to send a command line command multiple times

Tags: command-line, serial-port, command, teraterm

I have been working on a project that uses a program called TeraTerm to send commands to a TV via a serial port. I have discovered that when I open the program manually after a reboot, I have to open the correct port and then send the .dat command file several times before it actually takes (Turns off the TV).

The commands I am using are from [this](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/commandline/teraterm.html) page.

Anyway, I ran the command

```
TTERMPRO /C=7 /DS /FD=C:\Commands\TurnOffTest3.dat  /FD=C:\Commands\TurnOffTest3.dat /FD=C:\Commands\TurnOffTest3.dat
```

hoping that it would allow me to send the file multiple times. The TeraTerm window did open as usual, but the file was either not sent or had no effect.

There is a very high likelyhood that I am sending the commands incorrectly, as I am very new to the command prompt itself. Is there a way that I can call the command to send a file multiple times? If I am not interpreting the interface given on the website correctly or even if the way I am using the commands is just flat out wrong, any and all advice is welcome.

Side note: yes, I am sure that the command file that I am sending is the correct one because when I send the file manually (i. e. use the GUI) the TV turns off as expected.

EDIT: I have tried sending the file with and without quotes in its name.

Comment: `for /L %%G in (1,1,3) do TTERMPRO …` Read about [FOR command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html). This variant could help: [FOR-List of numbers](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Comment: I may be misunderstanding exactly what the %%G does (and yes, I checked the link first). When I run this command I get a response saying that "%%G was unexpected at this time". Thoughts? @JosefZ

Comment: Nvm, I just realized that i should only be using one %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /L %G in (1,1,3) do TTERMPRO …
```

Read more in [FOR command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html):

> If you are using the `FOR` command **at the command line** rather than
>   in a batch program, **use just one percent sign**: `%G` instead of
>   `%%G`.

Noticed in [`help` information about system commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732595.aspx) `for /?` as well: To use the `FOR` command **in a batch program**, specify `%%variable` instead of `%variable`.  Variable names are case sensitive, so `%i` is different from `%I`.

```
==> for /?
Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.

FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.
…
```

Further reading in [Syntax: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)